# String new line characters within a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have this string:

```
"“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”\n    ―\n    Babe Ruth"
```

which I have managed to strip to this:

```
“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”\n ―\n Babe Ruth
```

using this regex:

```
/^"(.*)"/
```

Now I need to strip both new line characters and also remove the excess white space. This is what I would like to return:

```
=> "It's hard to beat a person who never gives up." - Babe Ruth
```

Can anyone give me a hint please?

Comment: I don't see any excess whitespace

Comment: Are you trying to strip the literal "\n" from your text?  Or the hard return `\n`?

Comment: The regex you showed wouldn't eliminate the spaces you eliminated. Is that the change you wanted to achieve?

Comment: you wont achieve this in one operation with regex, so just use regex to get string then some ruby method to remove newline

Comment: Your sample result has different quote characters. Do you want to strip the curly quotes, or convert them to straight quotes? Also, the hyphen changed from an em-dash to a normal hyphen.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking, but I *think* you want something like this:

```
s = "“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”\n    ―\n    Babe Ruth"
s.gsub(/\s+/, " ")
# => "“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.” ― Babe Ruth"
```

That says, "Replace any one or more whitespace characters with a space."

Comment: I want to achieve: 

=> "It's hard to beat a person who never gives up." - Babe Ruth

Comment: Other than the different form of quotation and dash characters, that's the result above.  (The quotes around the output above are because it's a string; if you print the string, you won't see those.)

Comment: Tried it and print (as opposed to puts) does remove the quotes around the output. Thanks!

Comment: The regex can be simply `\s+`.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Thanks!  That is indeed more idiomatic (and simpler); I'm not sure what my brain was doing before.

Comment: @DarshanComputing Well, it’s possible that `\s{2,}` is more efficient as it may not needlessly replace single spaces with spaces, but that’s up to `gsub`’s internals.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#squeeze` to remove consecutive characters and `String#gsub` to remove the newlines:

```
string = "\“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.\”\n    ―\n    Babe Ruth'"

string.squeeze(' ').gsub("\n", '')                                                                                              
#=> "“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.” ― Babe Ruth'"
```

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.htm

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to go about this, depending on what you want as a final result.

As a starting point:

```
# encoding: UTF-8

puts "“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”\n    ―\n    Babe Ruth".gsub(/\s\s+/, ' ')
# >> “It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.” ― Babe Ruth
```

Your sample result doesn't have curly quotes or a hyphen (yours has an em-dash):

```
puts "“It's hard to beat a person who never gives up.”\n    ―\n    Babe Ruth".gsub(/\s\s+/, ' ').tr('“”―', '""-')
# >> "It's hard to beat a person who never gives up." - Babe Ruth
```